# Recyclerview data recycling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an e-commerce app in android and I used Recyclerview to display products. In each card, there is a counter to increase/decrease the quantity.

My adapter code:

```
class testadapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val todaylist: ArrayList<TodaydealItem>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<testadapter.MyView>() {

    class MyView(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var prodid: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prodid)
        var qty: EditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qty)
        var sub: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub)
        var add: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add)

    }

    private val quantityMap: HashMap<String, Int> = HashMap()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyView {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.testlayout, parent, false)
        return MyView(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyView, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = todaylist[position]
        val resources = context.resources
        val producturl =
            resources.getString(R.string.domain_url) + "api/v2/products/" + currentItem.id
        holder.prodid.text = currentItem.id
        val quantity = quantityMap[currentItem.id] ?: 1
        holder.qty.setText(quantity.toString())

        holder.add.setOnClickListener {
            val currcount = holder.qty.text.toString()
            val currcountasnum: Int? = currcount.toIntOrNull()
            val stringRequest = StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                producturl,
                { s: String? ->
                    try {
                        val jsonObject = JSONObject(s.toString())
                        val dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")

                        if (dataArray.length() > 0) {
                            val dataObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(0)

                            if (dataObject.has("current_stock")) {
                                val currentStock = dataObject.getInt("current_stock")
                                if (currcountasnum!! < currentStock) {
                                    holder.qty.setText((currcountasnum + 1).toString())
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        context,
                                        "Maximum Stock Reached!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            ) { volleyError: VolleyError ->
                Toast.makeText(context, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
        }
        holder.sub.setOnClickListener {

            val currcount = holder.qty.text.toString()
            val currcountasnum: Int? = currcount.toIntOrNull()
            if (currcountasnum!! > 1) {
                holder.qty.setText((currcountasnum - 1).toString())
            } else {
                holder.qty.setText((currcountasnum - 1).toString())
            }

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todaylist.size
    }
}
```

The issue is, when I add some items by increasing the counter, it automatically goes back to 0 if scroll. Is there any way to stop that and keep the quantity still?
[sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqLP3.png)

I tried it without the Hashmap. that keeps the data. But, in that method, more than one product's quantity changes without even touching them.

Comment: Try updating the value in `quantityMap` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just update data on ViewHoler by call `holder.qty.setText()`, so when scrolling the onBindViewHolder will get value from `quantityMap` and re-render

You should update `todaylist` and call notifyItemChanged to re-render this view holder. I think no need to use HashMap to store qty, should use only one collection to load list data, can create field quantity into item of `todayList`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyView, position: Int) {
  //...
  holder.add.setOnClickListener {
     if (currcountasnum!! < currentStock) {
         todaylist[position].quantity = (currcountasnum + 1).toString()
         notifyItemChanged(position)
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: More than one data changes automatically when I inc/dec the counter. I used Hashmap to overcome it. 
I did not store the quantity in the Arraylist "todaylist". Just in the variable in the code above
Reg your code, the same issue persists. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Because of the laws of MVC, I don't add any actual click listeners inside an adapter. What I have are callbacks that gets invoked inside the adapter and the calling function listens to.

So inside the adapter, I have something like:

```
class SomeAdapter(val itemLst: MutableList<ItemModel>, val ctx: FragmentActivity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
    private lateinit var binding: AdapterItemBinding
    var onItemClick: ((ItemModel) -> Unit)? = null
    var onCloseClick: ((ItemModel, Int) -> Unit)? = null

    ...usual boiler plate
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SomeAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = itemLst[position]
        holder.bind(item)
    }
    
    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: AdapterSocketNotifBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: ItemModel){
            binding.item = item
            
            //the important part for this question
            binding.someView.setOnClickListener{
                onCloseClick?.invoke(itemLst[adapterPosition], adapterPosition)
            }
        }
        
        //and this
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick?.invoke(itemLst[adapterPosition])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the calling side, wherever you instantiate this adapter:

```
itemAdapter.onCloseClick = { it, pos ->
    run {
        //do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

For the single argument click listeners, it's much simpler

```
itemAdapter.onClick = {
    //the variable it would automatically be equal to SomeItem
}
```

I know this answer seems quite convoluted, but what I wanted to show is a way for you to have easy access to your `Fragment` or `Activity` variables so you don't have to wrap your head around how you'll update variables that your adapter probably don't have have an easy access to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the counter value in model class of your list, so whenever you get value from that in `onBindViewHolder()` it'll get the proper value and not reset the counter. And Yes, you'll have to do `notifyItemChanged(position)` when you change the counter on click.